# Optimization (LPP) in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, linear-programming

This is not exactly related to programming.

I would like to solve linear programming problem in MATLAB without using the in-built functions like linprog from toolboxes.

Any suggestions or examples are much appreciated.

Comment: Are you planning to write your own solver or is it ok to use a solver that is not built-in?

Comment: @ErwinKalvelagen: It is ok use a solver that is not built-in. But I would like to learn to write my own solver.

Comment: When writing your own LP solver you first need to decide what algorithm to implement: (1) textbook  tableaux Simplex solver, (2) Revised Simplex or (3) Interior point.  There are quite a few matlab scripts to get you started (use google). Also I can recommend to consult a good book. E.g. Vanderbei, Linear Programming: Foundations and Extensions,

Comment: @ErwinKalvelagen: Thank you :)

Comment: @AbhayBhadani The most accessible text on implementing a LP-solver i read is ```Numerical Optimization (Nocedal, Wright)``` which is to my surprise available [here](http://home.agh.edu.pl/~pba/pdfdoc/Numerical_Optimization.pdf). Sadly, there is more about Interior-point methods than Simplex-based methods, but the latter do have many advantages (the most important: easier to implement something which is not that bad regarding performance and numerical-stability). A complete sparse IPM-based LP-solver for problems in standard-form should not need more than 100-150 lines of code.